# Usage of "extensive participation"

Tags: meaning, expressions, adjectives

What exactly does '*extensive participation*' mean?

Can I use this phrase in a sentence like this:

> Due to her **extensive participation** she hardly got time for her studies.

Comment: I'm afraid not. You could probably say 'frequent participation'. *Extensive participation* is generally used in reference to a particular event or type of events, usually by many people. However, the only exception I could find is the use of the adjective 'extensive' as a classification representing 'number of times', in contrast to 'intensive' meaning 'number of hours', of participation -- this is not the general implication, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intrinsic problem with the phrase *extensive participation*. It is only meaningful in your sentence, however, if it is already clear (or is made explicit) to the listener or reader what the participation is in. For example:

> Due to her extensive participation in the school's sports program she
>   hardly has/had time for her studies.

In such a context, *extensive participation* would mean that she is/was involved in many different sports.